# Why are my android app changes only showing the first time I run it?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-emulator

I'm working on a fairly simple app. It has 3 activities, each with a picture as a background with a different TextView displaying different strings over the image. My environment: Mac OSX Yosemite, Eclipse Juno version 23.

Here's my issue. I'll make a change, such as altering the text from "123456789" to "012345678", and run the app. Logcat and the console display no errors and says the app has been installed. I open the app on either an emulator or device, and it shows the changes I've made ONLY on the first time I run the app. If I make any additional changes, they will not be picked up. I have tried deleting and re-creating my emulator, and it doesn't work. I've tried setting it to wipe previous data, but that doesn't work either. Eclipse will only recognize my Samsung Galaxy S3 ONCE. Then when I try to run it again on the phone, it doesn't come up as a device. If I restart my computer completely, it will all work again, but only once. It's driving me insane and I've spent 2 days trying to resolve it. I haven't found any information online that I haven't tried. It's as if restarting my computer wipes some data so that it'll work again, but where?

Here's my main activity.

```
package com.autotec.nfcdemo;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
private NfcAdapter nfcAdapter;
private ListView listView;
private IsoDepAdapter isoDepAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
        null);
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.

    // int id = item.getItemId();
    // if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
    // return true;
    // }
    // return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_joe:
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    case R.id.action_jane:
        intent = new Intent(this, Jane.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    case R.id.action_john:
        intent = new Intent(this, John.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}

}
```

Here's the MainActivity XML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
android:background="@drawable/card"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="85dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="250dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:typeface="serif"
    android:text="123456789" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And here's my AndroidManifest.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.autotec.nfcdemo"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc.hce" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="19"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/aa_launcher_icon_high"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >


    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".Jane"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_jane" >
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".John"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_john" >
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing to check is your console logs... sometimes it will say something along the lines of : **Warning: Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front**" If this happens your new changes are not necessarily loaded...This is usually caused by unfinished dialogs or toasts etc.
The way to avoid this is close the app manually on the simulator before loading new versions.

If this doesn't resolve your issue, be sure to clean your project before building and loading. (**in eclipse, project->clean**...)

Good luck!

Comment: Closing the app on the simulator has worked so far. Can't believe I let this give me such a headache and the fix was fairly straightforward!

Comment: @TeeBee Straightforward, yes, but far from obvious or logical... #simulatorProblems

Answer (score 1):

Can you show us "where" did you make that change?! As far as I can see, the TextView has the value "123456789" and that would be the one that it's going to show every time you open the app.

You can make this on the onCreate:

```
TextView yourTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1)

yourTextView.setText("012345678");
```

and that would change the text from "123456789" to "012345678" every time you open the app.

You can simply change the android:text="123456789" to "012345678" if you don't need the 1st value.

Other way to keep your new value is by using a "SharedPreferences" and save that data (key value) on internal storage of your app and get it later or every time you open the app.

Comment: Yes, in the code itself I would change the text shown. From android:text="123456789" to android:text="012345678".

Comment: Always close the app every time you lauch from Eclipse or Android Studio. The activity something doesn't close and never really "updates" the app.

Also, make sure of using the "setText" in code. That way you'll be sure.